# Convert __NSCFNumber to Int32 Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a database setup on Parse.com, and one of the column has a type Number. 
When I pull the data from Parse, I'm given the error that I can't convert __NSCFNumber to Int32.

```
var index = word["index"] as! Int32
```

I can't seem to find any solution anywhere, could someone tell me what would be the correct way to convert __NSCFNumber type to Int32?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__NSCFNumber` is a subclass `NSNumber`. To get an integer out of an `NSNumber`, you would use its `integerValue` property:

```
var index: Int32 = word["index"].integerValue
```

Comment: Minor correction: `integerValue` returns `Int`, `intValue` returns `Int32`.